# Dotenv not loading env variables with correct path

Tags: node.js, express, dotenv

I'm using the `dotenv` library, but my env variables returns undefined

Here is `app.ts`:

```
require('dotenv').config({path: '/.env'});
console.log(process.env.MAIN_DB_PATH) // returns undefined
```

Here is my `.env` file:

```
MAIN_DB_PATH=./data/database.db
UPLOAD_MULTER_DIR=./module/car/uploads
```

My folder structure is

[image]

So it should works fine :(

Comment: @Danizavtz I tried but it still doesn't work :/

Comment: @Danizavtz also tried but not working. I already used . in others projects previously so im 99% sure that you can use them

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You do not need path if the `.env` file is at the root, but you can define a return value from config method and check if error happend

```
const result = dotenv.config()

if (result.error) {
  throw result.error
}

console.log(result.parsed)
```

source: https://www.npmjs.com/package/dotenv **config** paragraph

Answer (score 6):

To load the .env file in a different directory, you need to provide the absolute path to that file.

- `__dirname` : the absolute path to the directory of the file where you need to load .env file (app.ts in this case)
- `..` : go 1 level up

Then `path.resolve` will give you the absolute path to .env file

```
const path = require('path');
require("dotenv").config({ path: path.resolve(__dirname, '..', '.env') });
console.log(process.env.MAIN_DB_PATH);
```